# wpf dynamically add items to stackpanel with scrollbar

Tags: wpf, grid, scrollview, stackpanel

I am trying to create two columns of controls.  Let's say first column has 20 labels or buttons that user can interact with and second column has about 80 labels/buttons.   I'd like scrollbar as well.

when I add scrollview, my first column disappears.  How can I add scrollbar?

```
            InitializeComponent();
        Populate();
    }

    protected void Populate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= (int) 20; i++)
        {
            Button l = new Button();
            l.Content = i;
            StyleSP.Children.Add(l);
        }


        for (int i = 100; i < 170; i++)
        {
            Button l = new Button();
            l.Content = i;
            IndustrySP.Children.Add(l);
        }
    }
```

WPF

```
<UserControl x:Class="Factor.Control.FactorList"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="300" >
<Grid Height="300">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Name="StyleSP" Background="Chocolate"  Grid.Column ="0" Height="300">

        </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel  Name="IndustrySP" Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="1" Height="300">

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Set Grid.Column ="0" and Grid.Column ="1" to ScrollViewer

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need horizontal scroll bar.

There are two things need to do:

**1. Add property `IsReadOnly="True"` to your DataGrid**

**2. Add `MaxWidth="1200" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` to your `ScrollViewer`**

MaxWidth need to be set, you can change 1200 to any other value as you need.

```xml
<ScrollViewer MaxWidth="1200" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel  Name="IndustrySP" Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="1" Height="300">

    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <StackPanel Name="StyleSP" 
                Background="Chocolate"  
                Grid.Column ="0"
                Height="300"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Name="IndustrySP" 
                Background="AliceBlue"  
                Grid.Column ="1"
                Height="300"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: at least in my example, no scrollbar is visible with above suggestions

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that i neglected to move up 'Grid.Column' from StackPanel to ScrollViewer.